# Hover is not working properly with table.sorting_X

Tags: html, css, sorting, hover, html-table

I have a table with sorting (individual and multiple) and, IDK why, the hover doesn't show at the "sorted" column.

My code:

```
tr.odd:hover
{
    background-color: cyan;
}
tr.even:hover
{
    background-color: cyan;
}
tr.odd>.sorting_1:hover, tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1:hover
{
    background-color: cyan;
}
tr.even>.sorting_1:hover, tbody tr.even>.sorting_1:hover
{
    background-color: cyan;
}
tr.odd>.sorting_2:hover, tbody tr.odd>.sorting_2:hover
{
    background-color: cyan;
}
tr.even>.sorting_2:hover, tbody tr.even>.sorting_2:hover
{
    background-color: cyan;
}
tr.odd>.sorting_3:hover, tbody tr.odd>.sorting_3:hover
{
    background-color: cyan;
}
tr.even>.sorting_3:hover, tbody tr.even>.sorting_3:hover
{
    background-color: cyan;
}





tr.odd
{
    background-color: rgba(25, 119, 218, 0.26);
}
tr.odd>.sorting_1, tbody tr.odd>.sorting_1
{
    background-color: #132030;
}

tr.even
{
    background-color: rgba(16, 60, 106, 0.26);
}
tr.even>.sorting_1, tr.even>.sorting_1
{
background-color: #13304D;
}
```

(Kinda redundant, because I wanted to try as many possibilities as I can).

[example http://puu.sh/l8Cho/15ac04c94e.png](http://puu.sh/l8Cho/15ac04c94e.png)

But if I hover also the sorted column, like this,

[example2 http://puu.sh/l8Coh/5bf36bf642.png](http://puu.sh/l8Coh/5bf36bf642.png)

I want to also hover the sorted column(s) even if I don't hover it (I mean, I want to hover all the tr when I put the cursor on it).

HTML Code

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td class="match-number sorting_1"><a href="#25">1</a></td>
        <td class="match-rank rank-4 sorting_3" title="Cobre">4</td>
        <td class="match-clantag sorting_2">MiSCII</td>
        <td class="match-race race-Z" title="Zerg">Z</td>
        <td class="match-name">Eldoran</td>
        <td class="match-map">Cabeza de puente</td>
        <td class="match-length">00.15</td>
        <td class="match-result-loss">
            <span class="text-result">Derrota</span>
            <span class="points">-5</span>
        </td>
        <td class="match-date sorting_3">2015-10-22 07:54:41</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend of mine helped me, and found the way

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/1936/highlight-row-with-column-sorting-enabled

You have to, instead of all those :hover, make a simply

```
tr.odd td.sorting_1:hover {
    background-color: #ffff99;
}
tr.even td.sorting_1:hover {
    background-color: #ffff99;
}
```

Thanks and hope it helps in a future ^^